# Remove an object when on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, footer

for my site I have this login screen with a footer on the bottom. 
The page is optimized for a desktop monitor and the site itself is already optimized for both pc and mobile, so I don't want to go through the trouble of creating a new mobile version.

I'm not super good at working with scripts so that's why I'm asking it here: 
**can I make a script that removes the footer when the screen size is smaller than 400px?**

Here some photos of the problem and maybe you guys can give me a solution?
Thanks in advance!

[image: Normal desktop view]

[image: When on mobile, the footer covers it -> I want the footer removed]

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: if you are using bootstrap use .hidden-xs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS `@media`:

```
/* From 0 to 992px Device Width */
@media (max-width: 992px)  {

   #footer {
       display: none;
       // Other styles here
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are Using Bootstrap :

**Extra small devices Phones** (<768px) (Class names : .visible-xs-block, hidden-xs)

**Small devices Tablets** (≥768px) (Class names : .visible-sm-block, hidden-sm)

**Medium devices Desktops** (≥992px) (Class names : .visible-md-block, hidden-md)

**Large devices Desktops** (≥1200px) (Class names : .visible-lg-block, hidden-lg)

For more information : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

If You are Not You Will need to add @media queries for Your footer , supposing your footer class is .footer . Its media Queries Will be the following:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .footer {
        display: none;
    }
}
```